# Laminas Uncaught exception

Tags: magento2, template, exception, laminas

I am facing this issue:

```
Uncaught exception 'Laminas\View\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Laminas\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "error"; resolver could not resolve to a file' in /project/vendor/laminas/laminas-view/src/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php:497
```

Magento version 2.4.3P-1
PHP 7.4

Can anyone please suggest me the solution for this?

Comment: do you have the full stack trace of the exception?. From the looks of it, you are trying to render a template called `error` which does not exist. On what page does this happen?

Comment: happnes at /setup/index.php/session (homepage)

Comment: do you have any idea about this?